# Can ethtool provide the current incoming bitrate on a NIC

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, bitrate

Is there an option in linux's ethtool command that retrieves the current incoming bitrate or packets-per-second straight from the NIC?

Comment: Why not just `man ethtool` and search (with `/`) for it?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Inirn I tried that but didn't find anything. This was my last stop after researching for several hours. jww I'll keep that in mind for next time. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not per packets-per-second, but overall RX/TX.
You could write a script around it:

`ethtool -S <interface>`

For example currently on my wifi nice:

```
[user@host ~]$ ethtool -S wlo1
NIC statistics:
     rx_packets: 992535
     rx_bytes: 1010899932
     rx_duplicates: 3206
     rx_fragments: 878057
     rx_dropped: 4367
     tx_packets: 363876
     tx_bytes: 49823636
     tx_filtered: 1
     tx_retry_failed: 6567
     tx_retries: 160017
     sta_state: 4
     txrate: 40500000
     rxrate: 54000000
     signal: 181
     channel: 0
     noise: 18446744073709551615
     ch_time: 18446744073709551615
     ch_time_busy: 18446744073709551615
     ch_time_ext_busy: 18446744073709551615
     ch_time_rx: 18446744073709551615
     ch_time_tx: 18446744073709551615
```

The same information could be extracted from:

> - /sys/class/net//statistics/rx_packets: number of packets received
> - /sys/class/net//statistics/tx_packets: number of packets transmitted
> - /sys/class/net//statistics/rx_bytes: number of bytes received
> - /sys/class/net//statistics/tx_bytes: number of bytes transmitted
> - /sys/class/net//statistics/rx_dropped: number of packets dropped while received
> - /sys/class/net//statistics/tx_dropped: number of packets dropped while transmitted

Also see [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/356907/how-to-get-real-time-network-statistics-in-linux-with-kb-mb-bytes-format-and-for) for a specific real time solution.